# How to add 'id' attribute to elements in XML based upon other element values

Tags: php, simplexml

Would very much appreciate help on how to achieve the outcome below - being able to add the `id` attribute to the `<image>` tags with a PHP snippet or any methods.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <property>
        <images>
            <image id="1">
                <url>http://www.mywebsite/image?id=1&.jpg</url>
            </image>
            <image id="2">
                <url>http://www.mywebsite/image?id=2&.jpg</url>
            </image>
        </images>
    </property>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're reading in a string, then you can loop over `<images>` and add the `id` attribute to each `<image>`.

*Note: Your XML is throwing errors due to the `&` in your urls, so I've substituted them with `&amp;` for the sake of a working example.*

```
header('Content-Type:text/plain');
$xmlstring = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <property>
        <images>
            <image>
                <url>http://www.mywebsite/image?id=1&amp;.jpg</url>
            </image>
            <image>
                <url>http://www.mywebsite/image?id=2&amp;.jpg</url>
            </image>
        </images>
    </property>
</root>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstring);

foreach ($xml->property->images->image as $image)
{
    parse_str(parse_url($image->url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $querystring);
    $image->addAttribute("id", $querystring['id']);
}

echo $xml->asXML();
```

This same method could also be achieved by reading in an XML file instead of a string:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('path/to/file.xml');
```

Comment: Thank you for your very prompt reply (very new to the PHP & Xml environment) I have failed to supply enough info to you as most of the PHP code currently works producing the correct simplexml document I require including this php code which only needs the id=”1” attributed added to each image tag (2 shown repeats up 10) 
</$output .= "<images>"."<image>"."<url>".$image1."</url>"."</image>"."<image>"."<url>".$image2."</url>"."</image></images>\n";  I would really appreciate any advice Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to create xml same has above

```
$array = array(
        "http://www.mywebsite/image?id=1&.jpg",
        "http://www.mywebsite/image?id=2&.jpg"
);

header('Content-Type:text/plain');
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<root></root>");
$property = $xml->addChild('property');
$images = $property->addChild('images');

foreach($array as $link) {
    parse_str(parse_url($link, PHP_URL_QUERY), $query);

    $image = $images->addChild('image');
    $image->addAttribute("id", $query['id']);
    $url = $image->addChild("url", urlencode($link));
}

echo $xml->asXML();
```

Comment: @Bada Thank you for your very prompt reply (very new to the PHP & Xml environment) I have failed to supply enough info to you as most of the PHP code currently works producing the correct simplexml document I require including this php code which only needs the id=”1” attributed added to each image tag (2 shown repeats up 10) 
</$output .= "<images>"."<image>"."<url>".$image1."</url>"."</image>"."<image>"."<url>".$image2."</url>"."</image></images>\n";
I would really appreciate any advice Thanks again.